# SELECT query based on given attribute value

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have a simple query that isn't working.

```
select * 
from table 
where '"Name (xyz)"' LIKE '%AB CD EF G%';
```

I am trying to return the row such that the column Name (xyz) = AB CD EF G .
I have checked and my database does contain such a data entry but still the query yields 0 results yet no error messages.
The spaces in the column name and desired search parameter are there by design.

Comment: I am not understanding what `'"Name (xyz)"'` is supposed to represent?  Right now you are asking if the string `'"Name (xyz)"'` is `LIKE` the string `'%AB CD EF G%'` which I am pretty sure is not your intent.

Comment: '"Name (xyz)"' Is the column name. So i am trying to return rows such that this column has the value ```LIKE '%AB CD EF G%'```

Comment: Then no single quotes as that turns the identifier(column name) `"Name (xyz)"` into a string.

Comment: BTW, *"such that the column Name (xyz) = AB CD EF G"* translates to `"Name (xyz)" = 'AB CD EF G'`, no `LIKE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
select * 
from table 
where "Name (xyz)" LIKE '%AB CD EF G%';
```